# How do I use this Indian coffee maker?

Tags: brewing-process

A friend gave me an Indian coffee maker, which looks like this:

[image]

It did not come with instructions - how do I use it?

Answer (score 9):

I found a youtube video for this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YLwO2ylP6T4

And a post explaining the process: http://www.padhuskitchen.com/2012/05/south-indian-filter-coffee-how-to-make.html

So from the above site:

1. Put 3 tbsp of coffee powder in the upper container, fix it on top of the lower container and tap the container gently, so that the powder will settle evenly.
2. Bring water to rolling boil and pour it over the coffee powder. Close it with a lid and leave it undisturbed for 10-15 minutes.
3. The coffee decoction will get collected in the lower container (See picture 3).
4. Boil milk and simmer for a few minutes stirring continuously. Pour needed decoction in a cup and add milk and sugar to taste. If you want it strong, add more decoction, if you prefer mild coffee, add less decoction. Serve hot and frothy in tumbler and davara. Enjoy the aroma and the taste of South Indian filter coffee.

Answer (score 4):

You need really finely ground coffee powder, finer than espresso. Most South Indian families (where this filter is primarily used) use a mix of chicory and coffee, but thats really up to you.

Put the coffee in the upper container, the one with the perforations on the bottom. Tamp it down a bit with the plunger and leave the plunger there.

Add just enough water to saturate the grounds (the water temperature should be just below boiling) and let them bloom for about 30 seconds.

Fill up the upper container with the remaining hot water (remember to keep the plunger down), put on the lid and wait for some fresh drip brew to percolate.

This style of coffee is generally mixed with hot full cream milk and then manually frothed by pouring it between two tumblers. I prefer just mixing it with hot water Americano style, but that's up to you.