# What coffees can I make with a briki?

Tags: equipment, coffee-culture, turkish-coffee

I have a briki at home and was wondering what types of coffee can I make with it apart from Greek coffee, yack.
Anything like cappuccino/latte/americano?

Comment: Hi @IgorTatarnikov, could you add a photo of what you have?  If you have a regular ibrik/cezve your options are quite limited.

Comment: You could filter it after brewing to have a more round cup. You don't have to boil it, you can also just steep it at a lower temperature and then filter. But that's about all you can do.

Comment: @MTSan http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MzgyWDUwMA==/z/bc0AAOxy0x1TWIhp/$_3.JPG?set_id=2

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [cezve shown](http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MzgyWDUwMA==/z/bc0AAOxy0x1TWIhp/$_3.JPG?set_id=2) by @IgorTatarnikov, I can say the options are really limited.

The cezve presented here is an electrical Turkish coffee pot with proper quality.

Decoction brewing technique (mixing grounds and water together, then heat them up) and their alternatives are the only ones you can do. Worse, you cannot slow down heating in an electrical pot. Actually, quick heating is something desired for good Turkish coffee. But, you cannot use this for [mırra](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/3074/what-is-m%C4%B1rra-the-over-brewed-turkish-coffee), for example.

Adding flavors may be an option. Like cardamom, mastic, etc. to diversify the Turkish coffee.

Another option which is rarely made in Turkey is adding milk after preparing the coffee. First, you need to wait a while for the grounds settle down. Then, pour the non-grounded part on another cup and add warm milk. It resembles [Indian coffee](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/217/how-do-i-use-this-indian-coffee-maker), but without sugar. And you cannot use their fancy filtering equipment. This may resemble latte a bit. But, I can't think of any other options.

One side note... Such an electrical pot is a cool device to quickly heat up water. So, if you also place a few more cups and grab some filters you can filter your own coffee. When I was a student, I used to use this a lot. I used a similar machine to prepare Turkish coffee at the same time I directly filter my grounds with a Melitta filter on my cup.